# (PHP) Подскажите как посчитать процент скидки?

Tags: php, javascript, html, joomla

Помогите разобраться. На сайте если в акции добавлено несколько вариантов покупок, то показывается среднее значение скидки:

[image: Скрин]

Как сделать что бы бралось минимальная скидка? Нашел код, который я так понял отвечает за вывод скидки, но что изменить не могу разобраться:

```
<dl class="discount">
                <dt><?php echo empty($deal->origin_price)? 100 : (100 - intval($deal->price/$deal->origin_price*100))?>%</dt>
                <dd><?php echo JText::_('TITLE_DISCOUNT')?></dd>
```

Полный код - [код](http://dropmefiles.com/W2mD3)

Comment: Нужно смотреть код где собираются данные в переменную $deal, по коду вбюхи не понять что это за число, среднее получается 63% примерно, а тут 60%

Comment: Полный код - http://dropmefiles.com/W2mD3

Comment: Уже 3 недели мучаюсь) Не могу победить! Сил нет)

Comment: @РоманПавленко хороший программист с фриланса разберется в проблеме в течении часа, для данного сайта вопрос слишком общий.

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
 <dl class="discount">
                <dt><?php echo empty($deal->origin_price)? 100 : (100 - intval($deal->price/$deal->origin_price*100))?>%</dt>
                <dd><?php echo JText::_('TITLE_DISCOUNT')?></dd>
            </dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сделать так:

```
<dl class="discount">
        <?php
        $minPercent = 100;
        if (!empty($deal->origin_price) && $deal->types) {
            foreach ($deal->types as $type) {
                $currPercent = DealType::percent($type->origin_price, $type->price);
                if ($currPercent < $minPercent) {
                    $minPercent = $currPercent;
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
        <dt><?php echo $minPercent ?>%</dt>
        <dd><?php echo JText::_('TITLE_DISCOUNT')?></dd>
```